# Guardar valores de un formulario en una tabla de la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Estos son los campos del formulario:

[image: Captura de pantalla mostrando los campos del formulario]

Deseo poder guardar los cambios que haga en las diferentes filas de la misma (cambiar la cantidad o el descuento o ambos en varias filas).

No sé cómo hacerlo. Esto está hecho en PHP y así se desea hacer la acción.

Os dejo imagen de como esta el código de mi tabla para que vean como genero esos campos del formulario.

[image: Captura de código HTML]
¿Cómo guardo todos los cambios que se hagan en los diferentes campos del formulario?

Éste es el contenido de `controller_edit_venta.php`:

```
<?php 
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbsistema');

if (isset($_POST['agg_producto'])) {
    $venta_id = $_GET['idvnt'];
    $articulo_id = $_GET['articulo'];
    $precio_id = $_GET['preci'];

    $cantidad_arti =0;
    $descuento = 0;



    $query_newrow = "CALL `SP_EDITAR_FACTURA`('INSERT', '', $venta_id, 
    $articulo_id, 1, $precio_id, 0);";
    $ADDROW = mysqli_query($conexion, $query_newrow);
    $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    header("LOCATION:$url");

}
if (isset($_POST['ELIMINAR_PRO'])) {
    $id_del = $_GET['del_ta'];
    $id_venta_del = $_GET['idvnt'];
    $query_DELrow = "CALL `SP_EDITAR_FACTURA`('DEL', $id_del, 
    $id_venta_del, '', '', '', '');";
    $DELROW = mysqli_query($conexion, $query_DELrow);
    $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    header("LOCATION:$url");
}


?>
```

la tabla

```
 <table id="detalles" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                                        <thead style="background-color:#A9D0F5">
                                            <th>OPCIONES</th>
                                            <th>ARTÍCULO</th>
                                            <th>CANTIDAD</th>
                                            <th>PRECIO VENTA</th>
                                            <th>DESCUENTO</th>
                                            <th>SUBTOTAL</th>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <?php $resu = mysqli_query($conexion, $query_vent);
                                            while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($resu)) { ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <form action="../modelos/controllers/controller_edit_venta.php?idvnt=<?php echo $id_vent ?>
                                                        &del_ta=<?php echo $mostrar['iddetalle_venta'] ?>" method="POST">
                                                            <button type="submit" id="ELIMINAR_PRO" name="ELIMINAR_PRO" class="btn btn-danger">X</button>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td hidden><?php echo $mostrar['iddetalle_venta'] ?></td>
                                                    <td hidden><?php echo $mostrar['idarticulo'] ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $mostrar['nombre'] ?></td>
                                                    <td><input min="1" type="number" value="<?php echo $mostrar['cantidad'] ?>" name="cant_venta" id="cant_venta"></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $mostrar['precio_venta'] ?></td>
                                                    <td><input min="0" type="number" value="<?php echo $mostrar['descuento'] ?>" name="DESCU_venta" id="DESCU_venta"></td>
                                                    <td> <?php echo $mostrar['subtotal'] ?></td>
                                                </tr>

                                            <?php  } ?>

                                        </tbody>
                                        <tfoot>
                                            <th>TOTAL</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th>
                                                <h4 id="total"> <?php echo $FAC['total_venta'] ?></h4> <input value="<?php echo $FAC['total_venta'] ?>" type="text" name="" id="">
                                            </th>
                                        </tfoot>
                                        <tbody>

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ¿Podrías decirnos qué tienes de código hasta ahora tanto en el frontal (Javascript) como en el motor (PHP)?

Comment: Por favor, copia y pega el código en la pregunta, no compartas capturas de pantalla. Una captura de pantalla no nos ayuda en nada para leer y entender tu código, ni para reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Por lo pronto has de saber que tu código puede sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL). Estás concatenando el contenido de variables a código SQL. Deberías usar marcadores y consultas preparadas o, al menos, escapar las cadenas con [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/es/mysqli.real-escape-string).

Comment: @OscarGarcia no sabia, es un proyecto de practica... no responde mi duda, luego correguire el tema de seguridad

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el HTML igual que compartiste el PHP? No importa que sea un proyecto de práctica. Hay que aprender estas cosas bien desde el principio y no dejarlo "para luego". Cuando compartas el HTML te redacto una respuesta en la que te explico todo con más detalle.

Comment: @OscarGarcia esta bien solo el body, o subo toda la tabla?

Comment: Con eso es suficiente. Comienzo la redacción en un momento.

Comment: ¿Te sirvió la respuesta? ¿Sigues teniendo dudas o ayuda para hacer funcionar tu código? Déjame un mensaje en mi respuesta con la duda o el problema que tengas.

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar, debes encapsular todos los campos del formulario dentro de la etiqueta `<form>`. En la actualidad estás dejando dentro de un formulario únicamente el campo para la eliminación de los registros.

Una forma de hacerlo podría ser usando un formulario por cada campo que desees modificar:

```
<td>
  <form
    action="../modelos/controllers/controller_edit_venta.php"
    method="POST"
  >
    <input type="hidden" name="idvnt" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($id_vent) ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="del_ta" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($mostrar['iddetalle_venta']) ?>" />
    <input
      min="1" type="number"
      value="<?= htmlspecialchars($mostrar['cantidad']) ?>"
      name="cant_venta" id="cant_venta"
    />
    <input type="submit" value="Actualizar" />
  </form>
</td>
```

En el lado de PHP recibirás:

- El identificador de la venta (`$id_vent`) en `$_POST['idvnt']`.
- El identificador de detalle de venta (`$mostrar['iddetalle_venta']`) en `$_POST['del_ta']`.
- La cantidad a actualizar en `$_POST['cant_venta']`.

Otro método de hacerlo es mediante el evento `change` de los campos del formulario, pero esto tiene un inconveniente: no actualiza el campo en la base de datos hasta que se pierda el foco del campo o se pulse <kbd>ENTER</kbd> estando dentro de él.

También podrías usar el evento `keydown` para que se actualice con cada pulsación del teclado, pero eso provocaría cambios intermedios durante una edición (por ejemplo, al escribir "100" se actualizaría el valor a "1", luego a "10" y, por último, a "100").

Por último, puede hacerse todo a través de peticiones asíncronas sin recargar la página, usando `XMLHttpRequest` o `fetch`, pero en ese caso el código se complicaría.

NOTA: He agregado `htmlspecialchars()` allí donde se necesita para evitar que tu página sea vulnerable a XSS.

Comment: precisamente deseo evitar que por fila haya un boton actualizar. No sabia lo del htmlspecialchars() gracias, lo aplicare. Ahora, ¡El formulario debe ir dentro del while no es asi?, o puede ir fuera, (asi me avitaria el poner un boto actualizar digo yo). GAcias por responder, en temas de seguridad me has dado una bofetada bro

Comment: Cuando diseñas una interfaz de usuario debes evitar que el usuario realice ediciones accidentales y que pueda deshacer una edición si éste se arrepiente de ella. En la mayoría de casos los diseñadores optan por un botón de "Editar" a nivel de fila que permite comenzar la edición, tras lo cual aparecen un botón de "Guardar" y otro "Cancelar" para guardar los cambios o no. Además, estaría bien resaltar aquellos campos que han sido modificados.

Comment: Cuando tengas claro el comportamiento exacto que deba tener la interfaz de usuario puedo ayudarte con ello, pero tal y como has planteado la pregunta no das información de cómo debe comportarse.

Comment: El comportamiento es que, al darle en agreagr productos, añada una fila a la tabla, eso ya esta cubierto. Luego en los inputs poder editar las respectivas cantidades, es decir que en toda fila pueda agregar o quitar cantidades, y luego guardar todo desde un unico boton, sin que por fila haya un boton actualizar. Sino pues un boton por fila ni modo

Comment: Entonces, según entiendo, no estás "editando" un campo en particular, si no que quieres agregar un bloque completo (artículo, cantidad y descuento) de golpe. En tu pregunta estás diciendo "Deseo poder guardar los cambios que haga en las diferentes filas de la misma (cambiar la cantidad o el descuento o ambos en varias filas).". Agregar es fácil, con un único botón de guardar es suficiente, pero si deseas editar los anteriores el trabajo se complica.

Comment: si, en eso llevo atorado. Porque si tengo 3 filas, y en las 3 filas su valor incial (cantidad) es 1, por ejemplo, la persona pone a la vez un 3 en cada input que se guarden todos los cambios de cada fila, con un solo boton. El lote que mencionas